# "Path not found" error when trying to perform a checkout using SVNKit

Tags: java, merge, svnkit, vcs-checkout

I was getting to perform the checkout correctly before I merged branch and trunk. After that procedure (merge of folder trunk/Fontes and branches/1.1.0/Fontes, having trunk/Fontes as working copy), I'm having problems to checkout a project or update a working copy.

The message I get is the following: svn:E160013: '/svn/siaj/!/svn/bc/47/branches/Fontes' path not found: 404 Not Found. (where siaj is the name of the repository).

The message tells me the problem occurs in revision 47, which is the one in which the merge was performed. The thing is, the folder "branches/Fontes" doesn't exist and never did. The structure adopted was ever branches/x.x.x/Fontes (where x.x.x is the version of the system being developed).

The Java code is like this:

```
if(!SVNWCUtil.isVersionedDirectory(this.wdWorkingCopy)){
  this.wdWorkingCopy.mkdir();            
  this.updateClient.doCheckout(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(this.repositorio), this.wdWorkingCopy, SVNRevision.UNDEFINED, SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNDepth.INFINITY, true);     
}else{          
  this.updateClient.doUpdate(wdWorkingCopy, SVNRevision.UNDEFINED, SVNDepth.INFINITY, true, false);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: looks strange, could you try to perform the command with SVNKit command line and compare its behaviour to native Subversion?

Comment: Indeed. I did as you suggested and I got no errors performing the command both ways (with SVNKit command line as well as with native subversion). Extra info: the merge was performed using tortoiseSVN.

Comment: I noticed something even stranger. Even throwing the aforementioned exception, the folder seems to be versioned. The thing is, why is this problem happening if the checkout was completed ok?

Comment: SVN checkout can be canceled and continued any time, so it's expected that the directory becomes versioned very soon, even if checkout is not finished. SVN has special status for these directories --- "incomplete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was happening after the checkout... my mistake. The checkout/update process is just fine. I was trying to access a file in a directory that didn't exist in the repository.